# Custom Membership provider class with constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap

I added a custom Membership provider to my MVC project :

```
<membership defaultProvider="CodeFirstMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="CodeFirstMembershipProvider" type="CodeFirstMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and I also use DI, IoC (using structuremap) to get data from my Database so I need a constructor like this in my Custom Membership class:

```
public class CodeFirstMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IAccount _acc;

    public CodeFirstMembershipProvider(IUnitOfWork uow, IAccount acc)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _acc = acc;
    }
```

But problem is when I run my project and trying to use any method of `CodeFirstMembershipProvider` class I get this error:
`No parameterless constructor defined for this object`

How can I fix this problem?

**Edit 1:**
I changed constructor like this:

```
public CodeFirstMembershipProvider()
{
    _uow = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
    _acc = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IAccount>();
}
```

But I still get this error: `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`

**Edit 2:**
My `IoC` class:

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
            x.For<IUnitOfWork>().HttpContextScoped().Use<DbContext>();
            x.For<IAccount>().Use<AccountService>();
        });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the inner exception.

Comment: It's fairly hard to use the providers using any DI container, given the way that ASP.NET handles them at runtime. Have a look at how Castle can be used to get around that: http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/11/windsor-managed-membershipproviders.html - I'm sure Structure Map would work with the same pattern.

Comment: @TiesonT. Can you guide me how to implement it with `StructureMap`?

Comment: @mhesabi Unfortunately, I use Castle Windsor almost exclusively, so probably wouldn't be much help. I can take a look at the StructureMap API and see if it makes sense to me, though.

Comment: @mhesabi If it helps, these are the providers as I use them: https://github.com/tiesont/Gorilla/tree/master/Gorilla.Components/Providers/Membership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I ended up with using `ObjectFactory.GetInstance` and moved on. I don't know if this way is best practice or I encounter problem later but this is how my constructor looks like right now:

```
    using StructureMap;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IAccount _acc;

    public CodeFirstMembershipProvider()
    {
        _uow = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
        _acc = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAccount>();
    }
```